# Android split giving odd results

Tags: android, split

I have a string that contains a couple of GUID's and I am trying to split them out, however instead of the expected full field/string, I am getting only Characters/Bytes one at a time.

```
            String decodedQrText = qrCodeHelper.decodeQrFromUri(getContext(), attachment.internalUri);

            String[] separated = decodedQrText.split("|");
            String uGUID = separated[0];
            String uAPI = separated[1];
            String uEmail = separated[2];

decodedQrText =  e15457d9-7061-4ac5-ad74-179d5f8fb3ba|668afa73-2e5d-4860-a267-9889a247c1cd|myemail@hotmail.com
```

String uGUID contains an "e"

String uAPI contains a "6"

String uEmail contains an "m"

as opposed to what I would expect would be the full chunk up to the | separater ?

What am I doing wrong  ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this by using the following

```
String separated[] = decodedQrText.split("\\|");
```

Answer (score 0):

When you pass a `String` to `split` as a delimiter, it's interpreted as a regular expression. You probably intended to use just a `|` character instead of a regex "or".

Try changing

```java
decodedQrText.split("|")
```

to

```java
decodedQrText.split('|')
```